# How to do: All contents into one object in this case

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to modify object's key to given name + its key name and want to get all into one object.

Source:

```
aodl = {"name1": "Jhon", "name2": "Tiger", "name3": "Jack", ...}
```

When I tried

```
console.log(
Object.entries(aodl).map(([key, value]: [string, string]) => {
    return { ["aodl_" + key]: value };
  })
);
```

Then I get

```
[ {"aodl_name1": "Jhon"}, {"aodl_name2": "Tiger"}, {"aodl_name3": "Jack"}, {…}, {…}, ...]
```

I want to get all object's contents and I want to put them into one object

```
{
  "aodl_name1": "Jhon",
  "aodl_name2": "Tiger",
  "aodl_name3": "Jack",
  ...
}
```

How to do it?

Please let me know if you need more info about it.

Comment: If you want to go from n things to 1 thing, you generally want to `.reduce`

Comment: Can't many keys are same name in a object

Comment: many keys with same name it is not possible in javascript

Comment: add your aodl object in the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use simply `Object.assign()`

```js
const aodl = { name: 'John', name1: 'Wick' }
console.log(Object.assign({}, ...Object.entries(aodl).map(([key, value]) => ({['aodl_'+key]: value}))))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could either use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
var aodl = { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' },
    object = Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(aodl)
        .map(([key, value]) => ["aodl_" + key, value])
    );

console.log(object);
```

Or map single objects and get a single object with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```js
var aodl = { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' },
    object = Object.assign(
        {},
        ...Object.entries(aodl).map(([key, value]) => ({ ["aodl_" + key]: value }))
    );

console.log(object);
```

Comment: An object cannot have repeated keys.

Comment: right, i think op has shorten the wanted answer, but op takes an object and this has unique keys.